# Laravel 5.2 get user's notes and note's users

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relational-database

I have two tables:

> the first

Is **users** table which contain user information including user id.

> The Second

Is **notes** table which container user notes including note id.

I have relation `many to many` between them and I have my **intermediate** table between them that contain the `user_id` which matches `note_Id`.

Everything works perfectly but I want to get user notes and other users that have the same note.

> For example

**NOTE 1** users with id **1, 2, 3** can see it.

I want to use a query that get all the notes that the logged in user created and also `other users` that can view this note.

> what I have tried

```
$usernotes  = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user() -> id) -> first();
@foreach($usernotes -> notes as $usernote)
      {{ $usernote -> title }}
@endforeach
```

This return all the user notes but doesn't return the all note's users.

Comment: The statement `$usernotes  = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user() -> id) -> first();` will give you the current user, every single time. Better use `Auth::user()` directly for that. Regarding getting other users; you need to write another query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will get users (except an authenticated one as you ask) that have the same notes a currently authenticated user has:

```
Note::whereHas('users', function($q) {
    $q->where('id', auth()->user()->id);
})->with(['users' => function($q) {
    $q->where('id', '<>', auth()->user()->id);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
$loggedInUser = Auth::user();
@foreach($user->notes as $userNote)
      Note Title: {{ $userNote -> title }}
      @foreach($userNote->users as $user)
            User Name: {{ $user->name }}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

To exclude loggedInUser:

```
$loggedInUser = Auth::user();
@foreach($user->notes as $userNote)
      Note Title: {{ $userNote -> title }}
      @foreach($userNote->users()->where('id', '!=', $loggedInUser->id)>get() as $user)
            User Name: {{ $user->name }}
      @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I know how to get the user name but i am asking to get other users that share the same note

Comment: Thats what I have mentioned. $userNote->users gets all the users for that note. I will modify the code to only get other users (exclude loggedinuser)

Comment: This solution doesn't solve [N+1 problem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), so if the user has 50 notes, this code will create 51 queries instead of normal 2.

Comment: Yes that's right. Alexey's code is more elegant and better in performance